# Plesk 17 Mail doesnt work

Tags: email, smtp, plesk

I'm using Plesk 17 with my Node.js app.
as best as I could. I can receive e-mails from gmail, and I can send e-mails from my @mydomain to @mydomain. But I cannot send e-mails from @mydomain to anywhere else.
I get below error -

> postfix/smtp[27320]: A981CC1FE4: to=, relay=none,
>   delay=90, delays=0.3/0.01/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to
>   alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.130.27]:25: Connection timed
>   out)

Comment: Sorry but a down vote without explication means nothing!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the port 25 is blocked, so we have 3 options

```
1- Contact the ISP to unblock the port
2- Change the port in postfix to submission port 587 per example
3- Use other mail server.
```

Hope it helps someone.